# How do I make it CLEAR there is no sexual tension?

Tags: characters, romance, emotions

Both for the book I’m writing right now, but also for the future, how do I make it COMPLETELY clear that there is not, nor will there ever be sexual tension?

The relationship I’m focusing on currently will manifest into a father-daughter bond so if I write it well, it should remain fairly clear. But even so, people have a tendency, myself included, to ‘ship’ people as soon as there is some form of connection.

Also, simply showing dislike of one and other doesn’t work because of the possibility of an enemies to lovers trope. So even mistrust or irritation won't show definitively that a romantic relationship is impossible.

What are specific and clear examples of interaction or thought or emotion that cannot be interpreted as flirting or sexual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most people it is quite clear how they feel about someone they know. Romantic or erotic feelings and feelings of friendship are quite different from each other, and most people have no difficulty understanding what it is that they feel for another person. They will then have different **relationship goals** (have sex, have a romantic relationship, have a friendship) and act accordingly.

If you describe the emotions, relationship goals and relationship behavior of your characters, there should be no doubt for the reader what kind of relationship it is and what the characters intend. If both characters always think, feel, and behave according to a friendship, and if your story is about other aspects of life (that is, if it is not a love story but a story about a person dealing with loss or emotional problems or something else) – why should the reader assume a love story to evolve?

Also, most books today tell their readers what type of story they contain: **in the blurb**. Many writers forget this, but almost all books let the reader know on the cover what they will find inside. The title, the cover image, and most of all the blurb will make this unmistakeably clear, because authors and publishers don't want readers to pick up books expecting a historic romance but getting hard scifi. Because that will disappoint buyers, and disappointed buyers leave bad reviews. Therefore books about friendship will say something like "a story about friendship", love storys will have "a story of love" on its cover and a story with an erotic focus will point out "lots of steamy hot sex". Your readers will then expect just what you promised them.

There are some readers who want to read love stories and they will hope for it in all books they read. You cannot prevent this, and you shouldn't worry about it. It is not a problem of your writing, but just how these readers approach every book.

I would not ever introduce mistrust or dislike in a relationship just to not make it romantic. That's not what distinguishes friendship from a romantic or erotic relationship, so you shouldn't use it in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Part of it depends on the reader and unfortunately there are some (not many, thankfully) who will read sexual tension into everything. Nothing you can do, but also not worth trying.

With most people, you're safe if one of the characters is a small child. So I assume this is not the case.

If both characters are grown-ups, another thing that should make it very clear is giving them love interests. If either both of them are clearly involved with (or having a crush on) someone else, or one of them is and the other approves, then most of your readers should get the hint that they are not interested in each other, not even in an unrequited way.

Since a foster father wanting to marry his ward (who is not on the board with the idea) is an old traditional trope, it's probably the more likely danger that the man might come across as interested in the girl - less so the other way around. So I suggest to have him courting or dating a woman closer to his age - and not break up in the middle of the story.

That's the suggestion what you might do if you want to be extra sure. But the reader's comprehension doesn't hinge on that, and it shouldn't be in the least necessary to do anything specific.

What matters more is what not to do. Basically, don't give the reader any specific reason to get the wrong idea. Most importantly, don't play up either character's physical attractivity when writing from the other's point of view. That's not something one would realistically care about in a family member.

In fact, you don't have to show them actually liking each other very much - rather than that, show how they feel responsible for one another. Families are often people we wouldn't really choose over everyone else if we had the chance, so if you want them to have a relationship like father and daughter, feel free to give it a similar dynamic.

If you have them adore each other instead, then you run the risk it might be read as ambiguous. Doubly so if they start adoring each other after a period of intense dislike.

Comment: Thank you so much @Divizna ! This is really really helpful and super clear advice. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding flippant: you can avoid sexual tension in your story by not including sexual tension in your story.

Techniques you can use is to use multiple POVs of view to show how each character sees the other. Show their distrust and wariness. Show the characters' true fears and false beliefs that gives rise to this mistrust. Then, put them in situations where those false beliefs are challenged and that make their true fears too costly to hang on to.

The existence of a mature male and a vulnerable young female doesn't imply anything on its own.  Its the characters' actions and behaviors the determine what the story will end up being about.

If you are concerned that one character's motives will be misconstrued because of bias then go to lengths to establish the character's true motives.  Readers tend to trust the narrator of a story, unless the author is making pains to establish that the narrator is unreliable and that takes real effort to do. It doesn't happen by accident. Though sloppy writing can produce the same effect.